# JavaScript: How do I loop through one column at a time and set children to largest sibling's width before repeating in the next column?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to find the labels in a form-group column and set them all to the width of the largest label within that column.

My issue is that the for loop is finding ***all*** of the labels in the document and setting them to the width of the largest of those.

**How do I make the for loop only find the labels in the first column and set them to the largest label's width before going to next column?**

```js
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
var formCols = [...document.getElementsByClassName('form-col')];

formCols.forEach(labelSameWidths);

function labelSameWidths(){
    let labelWidth = '';
    for (i = 0; i < label.length; ++i){
            label[i].style.color = "deeppink";
            labelWidth = Math.max(labelWidth, label[i].offsetWidth);
            label[i].style.width = labelWidth + "px";
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Long Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Long Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried a nested loop wherein the outer loop was iterating through the formCols but I got the same result. When I debug, the label.length is always the length of all of the labels in the DOM. There must be an issue in how I'm calling the labels...?

Comment: Seems weird to need to do this. Why are you needing to set the width?

Comment: Easiest solution select each column and loop over, select the labels in that column.

Comment: @epascarello -- I have a form which toggles between readonly & edit. In edit, the labels sit on top of the inputs, in readonly they are left aligned & the inputs are styled to look like paragraphs. This is for an interface wherein the label text varies, dependent on language, etc. For best UX, in readonly, I need the space between the labels & text to be a readable width. I'm using bootstrap and flexbox so my page is dynamic and grows. Depending on the content of the labels, the growth needs to be restricted for readability. Thus, I can't set a width/min-width for the labels in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to set the width manually, seems like something done with CSS. But to answer your question, select to column and select the elements in that column.

```js
// Find the columns
document.querySelectorAll('.form-col').forEach( function (column) {
  // find label in columns
  var labels = column.querySelectorAll("label")
  // find the biggest width
  var max = Array.from(labels).reduce( function (max, label) {
    return Math.max(max, label.getBoundingClientRect().width) 
  }, 0);
  // set the labels to the biggest
  labels.forEach(function (label) {
    label.style.width = max + "px"
  })
})
```

```css
label { 
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Label</label>
                <input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Long Label</label>
                <input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Label</label>
                <input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Long Label x</label>
                <input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Label</label>
                <input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Some Label</label>
                <input>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! I commented above on why this functionality was needed. CSS wouldn't solve my problem this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is what you are lookong for

```js
for(let iCol=1;true;iCol++)
  {
  labels = document.querySelectorAll(`.form-col:nth-child(${iCol}) label`)
  if (labels.length===0) break;
  let widthMax = [...labels].reduce((m,l)=>Math.max(m, l.getBoundingClientRect().width),0) +'px'
  labels.forEach(l=>l.style.width = widthMax)
    
  console.log( 'col', iCol, widthMax )
  }
```

```css
/* just for test */

.form-col:nth-child(1) label { background-color: lightblue  }
.form-col:nth-child(2) label{ background-color: lightcoral  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some very Long Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Long Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want the labels in the first column, try setting an id for the first column:

```
 <div id='first-column' class="form-col col-sm-4">
```

Then you can use an if statement to check the parent node in your loop to see if the label belongs to the first column or not.

```
for (i = 0; i < label.length; ++i) {
        label[i].style.color = "deeppink";
        if (label[i].parentNode.parentNode.id === 'first-column') {
            labelWidth = Math.max(labelWidth, label[i].offsetWidth);
            label[i].style.width = labelWidth + "px";
        }
}
```

Comment: Not what OP is asking for